# problems with splitting a dataframe in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have a list of 1500 dataframes, each with 3 variables and 8 rows (generated with the function "split")

I would like to sort all of them (independently) by the column 2, and then, once sorted, I would like to eliminate all rows below a certain value in this column (column 2)

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance.

Tina.

Comment: Add some example data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tiny example.

```
# dummy list of data.frames
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(V1=sample(8), V2= sample(8), V3 = sample(8))
df.list <- list(df, df, df, df, df, df, df, df)

# function that does the job
df.out <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {
    x[order(x$V2)), ] # order by 2nd column using column name
    x[x$V1 > 3, ] # filter by some criteria
    # you can combine these two lines as:
    # x[order(x$v2)), ][x$v2 > 3, ] (thanks @Ananda for the suggestion)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

Sorting tends to be a slow process, you may be able to speed the process a little by doing the subset first before sorting.  Or you may not need to sort at all.

Any time that you want to split a data object into pieces, apply a function to each piece, then put the results back together, consider using the plyr package, it may make the process easier.

What is your final goal? it may be possible to do the whole thing in a simpler manner.